# How to schedule reading messages from azure service bus queue at a specific time of the day

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a requirement where i want my listener to dequeue a message from the service bus queue at a specific time of the day. Right now i am using Spring boot's @JmsListener to read messages and currently it is reading message as soon as there is an entry in a queue.

Comment: This sounds like a task for a scheduled job. Spring Boot has @Scheduled annotation (need app level @EnableScheduling). Take a look at this example https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/.

Comment: The listener function is taking argument that's why @scheduled annotation cannot work

Comment: You can create a schedule webjob to run on a specific time Or If you're publisher of message you can message schedule feature so message will be display/available to user consumer only after that time.